# How to make Drone Docker plugin to authenticate with a self-hosted registry having a self-signed TLS certificate

Tags: docker, authentication, ssl, x509, drone.io

I'm using Drone 1.0.0-rc1 with the [Docker plugin](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/). My docker registry is only accessible via TLS, however the certificate is self-signed.
The whole docker ecosystem complains about it with a similar error message, in case of the Drone build it's this:

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Normally I'm able to add the ca as a trusted authority to the OS running the different Docker solutions, however Drone is executing the builds (and the auth itself) inside a short-lived docker container.

How can I make it trust the cert?

Answer (score 0):

A less than stellar but working solution is to add the following setting to the .drone.yml:

```
insecure: true
```

This makes it running the docker daemon with the  `--insecure-registry` argument which according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

> First, try using HTTPS.
>
> - If HTTPS is available but the certificate is invalid, ignore the error about the certificate.
> - If HTTPS is not available, fall back to HTTP.

In my case I know that my registry isn't even exposed through HTTP so looks good enough.

Comment: Exactly where does the insecure setting go?  Its nowhere to be found in the documentation...